# RAND_MAX macro: signed or unsigned?

Tags: c

I've looked up the C standard (from 1999) and it only says that `RAND_MAX` should be at least 32767 but says nothing about whether this macro should expand to a signed or an unsigned int. The Single UNIX Specification ([link 1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stdlib.h.html), [link 2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/rand.html)) and Linux man ([link](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/rand.3.html)) don't add any clarity.

One would think `RAND_MAX` should be a `signed int` since that's what `rand()` returns.

However, I've found that some compilers define it as unsigned:

- The ancient Turbo C++ 1.01: #define RAND_MAX **0x7FFFU**
- The not so ancient C++ Builder 5.5: #define RAND_MAX **0x7FFFU**
- The still alive Open Watcom C/C++ 1.9: #define RAND_MAX **32767U**
- DJGPP (gcc 3.3.4 for DOS): #define RAND_MAX 2147483647
- MinGW (gcc 4.6.2 for Windows): #define RAND_MAX 0x7FFF
- MS Visual Studio 2010 ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dfe3bzd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)): *RAND_MAX is defined as the value 0x7fff*
- Tiny C Compiler 0.9.25: #define RAND_MAX 0x7FFF
- lcc-win32 3.8: #define RAND_MAX 0x7fff
- Pelles C 6.50: #define RAND_MAX 0x3fffffff *OR* #define RAND_MAX 0x7fff
- Digital Mars C/C++ 8.52: #define RAND_MAX 32767

This makes seemingly innocuous code like the below become non-portable and blow up due to signed to unsigned promotion:

```
cos(w * t) + (rand() - RAND_MAX / 2) * 0.1 / (RAND_MAX / 2);
```

`rand()` returns a `signed int` in the range [0,`RAND_MAX`].

If `RAND_MAX` is defined as an `unsigned int`, the value from `rand()` gets promoted to `unsigned int` too.

And if that's the case, the difference `(rand() - RAND_MAX / 2)` becomes an unsigned difference of unsigned integers with the value in the ranges [0,`RAND_MAX`-`RAND_MAX`/2] & [`UINT_MAX`+1-`RAND_MAX`/2,`UINT_MAX`-1] instead of being a signed difference of signed integers with the value in the range [-`RAND_MAX`/2,`RAND_MAX`-`RAND_MAX`/2].

Anyhow, it seems like `RAND_MAX` should be signed and most(?) compilers define it as such, but is there any authoritative source that says it should be signed? Older standard? K&R? Another UNIX spec?

Comment: The book _Standard C_ by Plaguer & Brodie (1989) on the ANSI/ISO standard says `RAND_MAX` is `<integer constant expression ≥ 32767>`. K&R's _The C Programming Language_ (2nd-Ed 1988) only mentions it in relation to the `int rand()` function saying the latter returns a value in the range `0` to `RAND_MAX`. Sounds signed to me.

Comment: @martineau Sounds unspecified to me. `integer` does not mean `int` exclusively, `unsigned` is as `integer` as `int`.

Comment: An unqualified `int` is equivalent to a `signed` or `signed int`, so it would be reasonable to associate the same rules to all uses of the word "integer" in the language specification. Besides that, the fact is that the sole purpose of `RAND_MAX` was to have something  with which to describe the limits of the values returned by the `int rand()` function only further strengthens that assumption. i.e. Why `#define` something to be an `unsigned` quantity which was only going to be used to specify the range of possible return values of a library function which returned a `signed` quantity?

Comment: @martineau Other than the standard not prohibiting it (= allowing it), I don't know why. The whole point of the question was to try to find not a reasonable assumption (and we have no problem with that part), but a place in the current standard (or its predecessors, including K&R) where `RAND_MAX` would either be explicitly required to be signed (or maybe even unsigned) or would be explicitly allowed to be either signed or unsigned. The current wording allows both implicitly. It could be for historical (=compatibility) reasons, so as not to render existing unsigned implementations invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: that code is making an unwarranted assumption, so it needs to be fixed.  What that code should have done is cast `RAND_MAX` to `(int)` on usage.

While it would make a bit more sense for compilers to define their `RAND_MAX` macros as signed, the standard carefully avoids requiring them to do so.  That makes it a portability bug for any code to blindly assume it to be signed.

Comment: Since nobody so far has found an authoritative answer to the main question "signed or unsigned?" and there's been enough time and it really looks like a flaw in the standard, I think the question can now be closed. Because the other answers express extra assumptions, which I find unreasonable, I'm choosing your answer.

Comment: I disagree that it's an "unwarranted assumption". See my comment under the question.

Answer (score 7):

Yes this looks like a defect in the standard.

First, nowadays probably nobody would define `rand()` to return an `int`. The intention is clearly to return a positive number and there is no error return that could use the negative returns. Such function would if it were introduced today be designed with an unsigned integer type as return type. My guess is that it predates C89 and the introduction of concept of unsigned integers to the language.

Then, clearly one has to expect that a definition of the maximum value that a function returns has the same type as the one of the function. At other places macros are well defined as expanding to expressions with a certain type so this would have been possible here, too.

As to your problem, I think the easiest to have something portable is to scale the value first to a double in `[0, 1)` by doing something like `rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0)` and to derive all your computations from there. In any case you should use `rand()` only as a last resort if your platform has no better pseudo-random generator available. E.g on POSIX systems the `rand48` family is a convenient replacement with well described properties.

Comment: I don't think it would return `unsigned` if it were designed today. Doing so would just lead to unnecessary and usually-harmful promotion to `unsigned`, in the exact form OP is describing.

Comment: @R.. opinion against opinion: I think it would, and `RAND_MAX` would be the maximum value of that unsigned return type. There is no reason to waste a bit for the sign here and not to have random "numbers" easily compose to wider random bit vectors.