# Is RAND_MAX guranteed to be <= UINT_MAX?

Tags: c, c99

I'm trying to determine if RAND_MAX can fit inside an unsigned int variable. After looking through the C99 standard, I have only found that RAND_MAX is guaranteed to have a value of at least 32767. While I know that RAND_MAX expands to int value, I'm not sure if it's a long int. Right now I'm working with unsigned long int variables, but I would like to simplify my source code to use unsigned int variables.

To summarize, is this assumption statement true for the C99 standard:

RAND_MAX <= UINT_MAX <= ULONG_MAX

Also, is RAND_MAX is explicitly less than (i.e. not equal to) UINT_MAX or ULONG_MAX. I realize that the value of RAND_MAX is often a Mersenne prime, but I'm not sure if this is a standard.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`RAND_MAX` is the maximum value that can be returned by `rand()`. Since `rand()` is defined as returning `int`, `RAND_MAX` will be no more than `INT_MAX`, and therefore also no more than `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @WhozCraig *integer constant expression* doesn't imply that the value fits inside `int`.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708433/rand-max-macro-signed-or-unsigned) is throwing me off since it seems to imply that a system could implement a rand function which returns unsigned and has a literal unsigned value for RAND_MAX.

Comment: @VilhelmGray: `rand` always returns `int`, and I don't see something in that link that suggests otherwise. Although some systems use unsigned literals for `RAND_MAX` for some reason, their values will still be `<= INT_MAX`.

Comment: @WhozCraig ecatmur objects to "By inference, INT_MAX limits integer constants".

Answer (score 3):

`rand` has signature `int rand(void);`, so any non-negative value it returns must fit inside an `unsigned int`, since the non-negative range of `int` is contained in the range of `unsigned int`.

This doesn't explicitly state that `RAND_MAX` is <= `INT_MAX`, but the requirement that `rand` return values in the range `0` to `RAND_MAX` along with the lower limit of 32767 for `RAND_MAX` indicates that `rand` is expected to cover the range `0` to `RAND_MAX`, which would not be the case if it were greater than `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945698/is-the-value-of-rand-max-always-2n-1).

I agree with the answerer to this question that the Mersenne Twister will give you all the control and speed you need. It's also a very easy addition to any C++ program.

But like many others have said, rand()'s return type of int virtually guarantees RAND_MAX to be less than UINT_MAX.

Answer (score 0):

> Is `RAND_MAX` guaranteed to be <= `UINT_MAX`?

Yes.

---

```
32767 <= RAND_MAX <= INT_MAX <= UINT_MAX
65535 <= UINT_MAX
```

---

> ... is `RAND_MAX` is explicitly less than (i.e. not equal to) `UINT_MAX` or `ULONG_MAX` (?)

No. `RAND_MAX` may equal `UINT_MAX` and `ULONG_MAX` in uncommon implementations.

Commonly `RAND_MAX <= UINT_MAX/2`, yet that is not specified by the C Library spec.

To assert this common case:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
_Static_assert(RAND_MAX <= UINT_MAX/2, "Large RAND_MAX");
```

---

> I realize that the value of `RAND_MAX` is often a Mersenne prime, but I'm not sure if this is a standard.

Not quite.  `RAND_MAX` is commonly a [Mersenne number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html) - a power of 2 minus 1.    It is not part of the C library standard, yet commonly a very desirable property.

To assert this desirable property:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
_Static_assert((RAND_MAX & 1) && ((RAND_MAX/2 + 1) & (RAND_MAX/2)) == 0, 
    "RAND_MAX is not a Mersenne number");
```

Sometimes `RAND_MAX` is a [Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).